# Why i'm getting exception when using SetPixel: SetPixel is not supported for images with indexed pixel formats?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the top of a class i'm doing:

```
private static Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(@"C:\Temp\New folder (17)\radar001486.GIF");
```

Then inside a method i'm doing:

```
private void test()
   {
    int current_list_length = pointtocolor.Count;
                for (int kk=0;kk<current_list_length;kk++)
                {

                    PointF pt = pointtocolor[kk];
                    e.FillEllipse(cloudColors[cloudColorIndex], pt.X * (float)currentFactor, pt.Y * (float)currentFactor, radius, radius);
                    bmp2.SetPixel((int)pt.X * (int)currentFactor, (int)pt.Y * (int)currentFactor, Color.Yellow);

                }
                bmp2.Save(@"c:\temp\yellowbmpcolor.bmp");
   }
```

Once it's getting inside the loop it's making the exception on the line:

```
bmp2.SetPixel((int)pt.X * (int)currentFactor, (int)pt.Y * (int)currentFactor, Color.Yellow);
```

If i will change the instance of bmp2 from:

```
private static Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(@"C:\Temp\New folder (17)\radar001486.GIF");
```

To

```
private static Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(512,512);
```

Then it will work but i want to SetPixel the pixels over the original radar001486.GIF and not on a new empty Bitmap.

Comment: The problem that SetPixel is facing is that the color you specify might not exist in the current palette.

Comment: you can check this post where it is the same theme  [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840138/setting-pixel-color-of-bmp-jpg-file-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a GIF as it has indexed pixels. Try converting it to a png if you can; or if you can't, turn it into a non-indexed image using:

```
public Bitmap CreateNonIndexedImage(Image src)
{
    Bitmap newBmp = new Bitmap(src.Width, src.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(newBmp)) {
        gfx.DrawImage(src, 0, 0);
    }

    return newBmp;
}
```

Note: if you have the option to do so (i.e. non-downloaded images, or you have access to the server), definitely convert those images to PNG instead.

Comment: Dracor this is working. The files on the website i'm downloading are GIF format. Should i save them as png ? Or they i'm doing it now using your soltuion does the new bitmap newBmp is lost some data(pixels) ?

Comment: No, you simply use the phone's GPU to render the image into another  image. I said not to use it if you don't have to because it's somewhat resource intense, but for a few images it's a working solution.

Comment: Dracor and if i will want in the future to insert automatic many images not only few like 3-5 or 10 images but a lot much a lot how can i do it so it will not use the phone's GPU so much ? If you have any idea and code. Thanks.

Comment: Technically speaking, if you are downloading hundreds of potentially large images with a mobile phone at the same time, you are doing something wrong.

If you really want to do that, you'll have to put the image downloading to background threads anyway, but don't forget that loading the images will take time.

Answer (score 5):

The image you are trying to change is an indexed GIF. This means that the image doesn't contain a series of pixels with their respective color values (as your new `Bitmap` does); rather, it contains a color palette combined with a series of pixels with their *index values into the palette*. The pixel format of your image loaded from disk is probably something like `Format8bppIndexed`.

You cannot use `SetPixel` on this kind of image, because `SetPixel` wants to set the R, G, and B values for the pixel directly. That's not how an indexed image works.

To change this kind of image you have a couple of options:

- Your best bet is to use WPF, which has a [GifBitmapEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.gifbitmapencoder(v=vs.110).aspx) and [GifBitmapDecoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.gifbitmapdecoder(v=vs.110).aspx). This lets you decode the GIF data into something WPF can draw on, then convert it back. Since this uses DirectX and not GDI+ it doesn't have the limitations of things like `SetPixel`. I'd really, really suggest you go this route if you can, but if not:
- Use GDI+ to [Convert the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671953/converting-from-a-format8bppindexed-to-a-format24bpprgb-in-c-gdi) into a non-indexed type of image, change it, and [convert it back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355135/c-sharp-converting-32bpp-image-to-8bpp). This is generally a terrible idea: GDI+ and indexed formats don't get along, and that includes encoding a bitmap as an indexed GIF. The image quality is likely to be terrible.
- Edit the byte data directly. For this, you need to extract the GIF data into an array and set the pixels to the correct indexed values. The trick here is figuring out the right index value; or, if there happens to be an empty one in the palette, you can just add another one. You'll need to dig deep into the GIF format to figure this out, though it's likely to be the most efficient in terms of both space and speed without reducing the image quality. Once you know what index value to write, you do something like this:

  ```
  var data = image.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), 
      ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

  var bytes = new byte[data.Height * data.Stride];
  Marshal.Copy(data.Scan0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

  bytes[5 * data.Stride + 5] = 1; // Set the pixel at (5, 5) to the color #1

  Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, data.Scan0, bytes.Length);

  image.UnlockBits(data);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your image type as it works fine with a .jpeg. You can get a [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Drawing.Bitmap);k(Bitmap);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) from an [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Drawing.Image);k(Image);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

Try changing to this:

```
private static Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(@"C:\Temp\New folder (17)\radar001486.GIF"));
```

Here is my complete test code:

```
    private Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(@"e:\temp\temp\yourGIF.gif"));
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp2;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var sz = bmp2.Size;
        for(int x= 0; x<sz.Width; x++)
        {
            for(int y=0; y<sz.Height; y++)
            {
                bmp2.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Yellow);
            }
        }
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }
```